# Setting Outlook appointment item category, for meetings where the invitation came from an external system: Object does not support this method

Tags: vba, outlook

The following code sets the categories of appointment items regarding text in subject and body.

`oFinalItems` is a selection of calendar entries and contains valid entries.

`dicCategories` is a dictionary that holds search strings and the assigned categories:

```
For Each oAppt In oFinalItems
    For Each Key In dicCategories.Keys
        If InStr(1, oAppt.Subject & oAppt.Location, Key, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            strCategory = dicCategories.Item(Key)
            If InStr(1, oAppt.Categories, strCategory, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                If oAppt.Categories = "" Then
                    oAppt.Categories = strCategory
                Else
                    oAppt.Categories = strCategory & ";" & oAppt.Categories
                End If
                oAppt.Save
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I get the error "Object doesn't support this method" in the line

```
oAppt.Categories = strCategory
```

This code was running before reinstalling my PC.

I checked the type and it stated "AppointmentItem". I just found out that it only doesn't work for meetings where the invitation came from an external system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the issue: you can not set the category for a recurring appointment, except this is the master/parent appointment. If it isn't the master, you can get to it using the Parent property.

This fixes this issue:

```
Sub SetCategory(oItem As Object, sCat As String)

If TypeOf oItem Is AppointmentItem Then
    If oItem.IsRecurring Then
        If oItem.RecurrenceState <> olApptMaster Then
            Set oItem = oItem.Parent
        End If
    End If

End If
oItem.Categories = sCat
oItem.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the code:

```
For Each oAppt In oFinalItems
```

The `Items` object may contain different types of items - MailItem, AppointmentItem, MeetingItem, DocumentItem and etc. Not all of them define the `Categories` property.

I'd suggest checking the item class or type before accessing any properties. For example:

```
  If TypeName(Item) <> "AppointmentItem" Then
     Exit Sub
  End If
```

Comment: I checked the type and it stated "AppointmentItem"... But I just found out that it only doesn't work for meetings where the invitation came from an external system... have to check that further... But nevertheless thank you for your advice.